# Kendo inline editing disturb, when edit a row if another row in grid already in edit mode

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We have a Kendo Grid with Inline Editing, Lets say we have two rows available under grid. We edit the first row and without saving that row, edit the another available row (second row). In that case the first row Action will have three buttons avalailable : Edit, Cancel, Undo.

We have the Id field available in model for this grid. And we have client side function on all the crud events to perform coloring functionality on that grid.

Grid code is available below :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProviderHealthPlanGridDTO>(Model.NewModel.ProviderHealthPlans)
.Name("healthplansGrid")
.Columns(cols =>
{
    cols.Bound(p => p.HealthPlanId).Hidden();
    cols.Bound(p => p.PendingChangeId).Hidden();
    cols.Bound(p => p.ProviderProfileFormFieldOptionSetting).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "ProviderProfileFormFieldOptionSetting" }).Hidden();
    cols.Bound(p => p.ProviderId).Hidden();
    cols.Bound(p => p.HealthPlanProviderId).Hidden();
    cols.Bound(p => p.IsRemoved).Hidden();
    cols.Bound(p => p.IsAdded).Hidden();
    cols.Bound(p => p.IsChanged).Hidden();
    cols.Bound(p => p.HealthPlanCompanyId).Hidden();
    cols.Bound(p => p.HealthPlanCompanyName).Width("20%").Title("Company Name").EditorTemplateName("HealthPlanCompanyAutoComplete").Sortable(true)
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false)))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "HealthPlanCompanyName" }).ClientTemplate
        (
            @"<span>#: (HealthPlanCompanyName != null) ? HealthPlanCompanyName : '' #</span>"
        );

    cols.Bound(p => p.HealthPlanName).Width("20%").Title("Health Plan Name").EditorTemplateName("HealthPlanAutoComplete").Sortable(true)
        .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false)))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "HealthPlanName" }).ClientTemplate
        (
            @"<span>#: HealthPlanName #</span>"
        );
    cols.Bound(p => p.InitialDate).Title("Initial Date").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "InitialDate" }).ClientTemplate("#= (InitialDate != null) ? kendo.toString(InitialDate, \"MM/dd/yyyy\") : '' #").EditorTemplateName("Date").Width("10%");
    cols.Bound(p => p.MostRecentDate).Title("Most Recent Date").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "MostRecentDate" }).ClientTemplate("#= (MostRecentDate != null) ? kendo.toString(MostRecentDate, \"MM/dd/yyyy\") : '' #").EditorTemplateName("Date").Width("10%");
    cols.Bound(p => p.NextActionDate).Title("Next Action Date").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "NextActionDate" }).ClientTemplate("#= (NextActionDate != null) ? kendo.toString(NextActionDate, \"MM/dd/yyyy\") : '' #").EditorTemplateName("Date").Width("10%");
    cols.Bound(p => p.TerminationDate).Title("Termination Date").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "TerminationDate" }).ClientTemplate("#= (TerminationDate != null) ? kendo.toString(TerminationDate, \"MM/dd/yyyy\") : '' #").EditorTemplateName("Date").Width("10%");
    cols.Bound(p => p.TierModel.Value).Width("5%")
                    .EditorTemplateName("DDL_TierModel")
                    .Title("Tier").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "TierModel" });
    cols.Bound(p => p.AcceptingOptionModel.Value).Width("15%")
                    .EditorTemplateName("DDL_AcceptingNewPatient")
                    .Title("Accepting Patients").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "AcceptingOptionModel" });
    cols.Command(command =>
    {
        command.Edit().UpdateText("Save").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = !Model.HealthPlansFormField.IsEditOnLanding ? "k-state-disabled" : "", @style = !Model.HealthPlansFormField.IsEditOnLanding ? "pointer-events: none;" : "" });
        command.Custom("Undo").Click("onUndoHealthPlanRemove").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = !Model.HealthPlansFormField.IsEditOnLanding ? "k-state-disabled" : "", @style = !Model.HealthPlansFormField.IsEditOnLanding ? "pointer-events: none;" : "" });
        command.Custom("Remove").Click("onHealthPlanRemove").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = !Model.HealthPlansFormField.IsEditOnLanding ? "k-state-disabled" : "", @style = !Model.HealthPlansFormField.IsEditOnLanding ? "pointer-events: none;" : "" });
    }).Title("Action").Width("20%");
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.Pageable(pageable => pageable
    .Refresh(true))
.Scrollable()
//.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
.Events(events =>
{
    events.DataBound("onHealthPlanGridDataBound");
    events.Edit("onEditHealthPlanGridRow");
    events.Save("onSaveHealthPlanGridRow");
    events.Cancel("onCancelHealthPlanGridRow");
    events.Remove("onHealthPlanRemove");
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Events(ev => ev.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
    .PageSize(10)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.HealthPlanId);
        model.Field(p => p.TierModel).DefaultValue(defaultTier);
        model.Field(p => p.AcceptingOptionModel).DefaultValue(defaultAcceptingOption);
        //model.Field(p => p.TierModel).DefaultValue(new TierModelDTO());
        //model.Field(p => p.AcceptingOptionModel).DefaultValue(new AcceptingNewPatientModelDTO());
    })
    .Create(create => create.Action("AddHealthPlan", "ProviderUpdate").Data("sendAntiForgery"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateHealthPlan", "ProviderUpdate").Data("sendAntiForgery"))
))
```

Please suggest and let me know if you need client side code snippets as well.

Below is the snapshot :

[image]

Comment: Any Kendo Expert ?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Are you trying to edit multiple rows? Perhaps you want [batch editing](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing)?

Comment: We dont want to provide edit multiple rows, but accidentally if someone try to do so than we are getting issue, shown in snapshot.